# Excel - Use VBA to modify a cell based on the sum of other cells in the row. Loop

Tags: excel, vba

In my sheet I would like to hit a button and loop through a series of rows and change A3 to contain "x" if sum(C3:F3) = 0 and "" if sum(C3:F3) > 0 then move to row 4, then row 5 then row 6, etc.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

do you mean in row 3 use the sum of row 3, in row 4 use the sum of row 4 and put the x also in row 4 and so on?

The easiest is to just use either use the index function (use the easy one where the index is the row into your array, or just write a little program that copies the formulas down, then you have everything automatically correct thanks to the relative references.

If you would post your code / show the row/column setup one could easily answer with the code and/or formulas

Answer (score 0):

No need for VBA.  Put this formula in A3 and fill down:

```
=IF(SUM(C3:F3)=0,"x","")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spreadsheet functions in VBA code, like so:

```
Dim Res As Variant
Worksheets("MySheet").Activate
Res = Application.WorksheetFunction.SUM("A1:C100")
```

The worksheet function will act on the currently active worksheet, so be sure to set that first.